# How can I view list result in a pentaho job?

Tags: pentaho

How can I see the result rows in a job?
Example when I use a transformation inside a job with the step copy to result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you can put a *File Output* or some other step like that before the *Copy to result* step to see the results afterwards.